# Best implementation for private and public APIs for spring cloud gateway based on AWS applications

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-cloud-gateway

I have AWS based ECS applications.
Now i want to create gateway based on spring cloud gateway.
Some endpoints must be public on internet with JWT authentication.
Other endpoints must be only accessible from our aws network frontend application which is protected by IP limits.

Can you suggest some best/good solution for private and public networks(EC2) working together in spring cloud network?

Or at least give some reference about this situation.